# Creating multiple 3x3 grids per text file line python 3

Tags: python-3.5

I am trying to create a 3x3 grid per line in a text file. The file has multiple lines of numbers but only 9 numbers in each line like this:

4 5 6 7 8 9 1 2 3

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

5 6 4 7 9 8 3 2 1

I cannot seem to figure out how to put each line into a grid. So i need it to look something like this:

4 5 6

7 8 9

1 2 3

This is my code so far but I could easily be dong something wrong:

```
f = open("numbers.txt")
    grid = []
    rowIndex = 3
    columnIndex = 3
    for lines in f:
        lines.split()
    for row in range(rowIndex):
        grid.append([0]*columnIndex)
```

It also needs to convert string to int using maping. Any help is much apreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to use `numpy` for that? It would be much better.

Comment: Also, how do you plan to represent the matrix structure? As a list of lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's unclear how you want to store each grid/line, but in this example I just append it to a list you can do whatever you need with that grid:

```
f = open("numbers.txt","r")
lines = filter(None, (line.rstrip() for line in f))
list_of_grids = [] #this will contain each line of the file as a grid
for line in lines:
    grid = [] #each line should be a grid
    n = 0
    row = []
    for number in line:
        try: #try to convert the string to an int
            num_to_append = int(number)
            row.append(num_to_append)
            n += 1
        except:
            pass #it's a space, ignore
        if (n!= 0) and n % 3 == 0:
            grid.append(row) #row is ready, added to the line grid
            row = []
            n = 0
    list_of_grids.append(grid) #append each line to the master grid
```

This will result in a list of grids like so, it can be easily change to however you wanted to look like:

```
[
  [[4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9],
   [1, 2, 3]],

  [[1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]],

  [[5, 6, 4],
   [7, 9, 8],
   [3, 2, 1]]
]
```